# When to use me vs. myself?

Tags: word-choice

When should you use me and when do you use myself?

Comment: These are different parts of speech. "My" is the possessive determiner and used to say that you own something.  "Myself" is a reflexive pronoun. It normally used when you are both the object and the subject of the sentence:

Comment: I'm sorry- I mistyped the first time and confused myself. I meant to write me instead of my. I've edited it but it hasn't come through yet.

Answer (score 1):

1-**Me**
Me is a personal pronoun that refers to one’s own self. Specifically, it is an objective pronoun. Me takes the function of an object in sentences.
It refers to the person that the action of a verb is being done to, or to whom a preposition refers.
Example:

- I’m sorry, I didn’t realize you were talking to me
- Give me that book, please.
- Tell me a story.

2-**Myself**
Myself is also a pronoun that refers to the speaker, although it is a different kind of pronoun than me.
Myself is a reflexive pronoun, meaning the speaker or writer would use it for self-reference. In other words, myself is used when the speaker both performs and receives the verb’s action, generally speaking, it should be used in conjunction with the subject pronoun I, not instead of the object pronoun me.
Example:

- I care for myself by running every morning and eating healthy food.
- I hurt myself falling down the stairs.
- I bought myself a car
- I feel like myself again.

Myself can also be used intensively, like in these examples:

- I, myself, like a little sugar in my coffee from time to time.
- Why would I pay someone to build me a shed when I could do it myself?
- Tired of waiting, I just did it myself.

3-Trick to Remember the Difference

- Me is a personal pronoun.
- Myself is either a reflexive pronoun, or an intensive pronoun.

In general, when the speaker is the object of a verb, but not the subject, choose me. When the speaker is both the subject and the object of a verb, choose myself. Since myself and subject both contain the letter S, this should be an easy rule to remember.